# Getting the latitude and longitude in the Log console in mapbox

Tags: android, mapbox, android-location, android-gps, location-provider

I'm trying to get the lat, long coordinates as a precise float number, in order to make some calculations for my application. I want to receive the current float location every one second, so I can calculate the distance between 'a point' and my current location... how can I solve this problem?
(I don't want to use my mobile app as a navigator).
Below is the code that I have done till now.Have you got any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback, PermissionsListener, OnLocationClickListener, OnCameraTrackingChangedListener {

    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    private MapView mapView;
    private LocationComponent locationComponent;
    private boolean isInTrackingMode;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
        // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));

        // This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the access token is configured.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("LocOptionsActivity", "isInTrackingMode = " + isInTrackingMode);


        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        MainActivity.this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
        enableLocationComponent();

    }


   // @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void enableLocationComponent() {
        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
            //
            LocationComponentOptions options = LocationComponentOptions.builder(this)
                    .elevation(5)
                    .accuracyAlpha(.6f)
                    .accuracyColor(Color.RED)
                    .foregroundDrawable(R.drawable.gps)
                    .build();

            // Get an instance of the component
            LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();

            // Activate
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(this);

            // Enable to make component visible
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

            // Set the component's camera mode
            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING_GPS_NORTH);


            // Set the component's render mode
            locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.GPS);

            // Add the location icon click listener
            locationComponent.addOnLocationClickListener(this);

            // Add the camera tracking listener. Fires if the map camera is manually moved.
            locationComponent.addOnCameraTrackingChangedListener(this);

           /*findViewById(R.id.back_to_camera_tracking_mode).setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if (!isInTrackingMode) {
                    isInTrackingMode = true;
                    locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);
                    locationComponent.zoomWhileTracking(16f);
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.tracking_enabled),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.tracking_already_enabled),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });*/

            //Set the component's zoom level
            locationComponent.zoomWhileTracking(22);

        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    @Override
    public void onLocationComponentClick() {
        if (locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation() != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, String.format(getString(R.string.current_location),
                     locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude(),
                   locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLongitude()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onCameraTrackingDismissed() {
        isInTrackingMode = false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraTrackingChanged(int currentMode) {
        // Empty on purpose
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This app needs location permissions in order to show its functionality", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            enableLocationComponent();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You didn't grant location permissions.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add location Engine to your location provider

```
private void enableLocationComponent() {
        locationEngine = new LocationEngineProvider(this).obtainLocationEngineBy(LocationEngine.Type.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
        locationEngine.setInterval(1000);//this is means get location every 1 second
        locationEngine.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(new LocationEngineListener() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onConnected() {
                locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                mCurrentLocation = location;
            }
        });
        locationEngine.activate();
        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {

            LocationComponentOptions options = LocationComponentOptions.builder(this)
                .elevation(5)
                .accuracyAlpha(.6f)
                .accuracyColor(Color.RED)
                .foregroundDrawable(R.drawable.gps)
                .build();
            // Get an instance of the component
            LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();

            //ADD THIS LINE 
            locationComponent.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);
            // Activate
            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(this);

            // Enable to make component visible
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

            // Set the component's camera mode
            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING_GPS_NORTH);


            // Set the component's render mode
            locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.GPS);

            // Add the location icon click listener
            locationComponent.addOnLocationClickListener(this);

            // Add the camera tracking listener. Fires if the map camera is manually moved.
            locationComponent.addOnCameraTrackingChangedListener(this);


            //Set the component's zoom level
            locationComponent.zoomWhileTracking(22);

        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }
```

Don't forget add `private LocationEngine locationEngine;` above of `onCreate()`

And this dependencie

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

Comment: when I'm adding this code, it returns me a blank page in the application... it shows up no map at all... why? :/

Comment: @oreocookiemaster please check your log cat and see exception. add above dependencie too

Comment: Error: Program type already present: com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngine$1$2

and it underlines with red this line of code: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Comment: if you add my dependencies you don't need com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngine . so just remove it

Comment: remove the 'implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
?

Comment: That's my error(if I remove the implementation)

 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mapbox.android.core.location.LocationEngine.setInterval(int)' on a null object reference
        at mapboxapp.mapbox.com.mapboxapp.MainActivity.enableLocationComponent(MainActivity.java:89)
at mapboxapp.mapbox.com.mapboxapp.MainActivity.onMapReady(MainActivity.java:79)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onMapReady(MapView.java:1648)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView$MapCallback.onDidFinishLoadingStyle(MapView.java:1686)